# Replacing expressions with variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, special-functions

I have a large matrix where the entries are rational in Jacobi elliptic functions e.g.

[image]

I'd like to replace the elliptic functions by variables, e.g.

```
JacobiSN[h ω,k] -> s
```

and similarly for `CN` and `DN`. Could anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: Usually, `ReplaceAll`   or related come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = -((2 23 (-1 + k^2 JacobiSN[h Ω, k]^4))/
            (k^2 JacobiCN[h Ω, k] JacobiDN[h Ω, k] JacobiSN[h Ω, k]^2));

rules = {_JacobiSN -> sn, _JacobiCN -> cn, _JacobiDN -> dn};
expr /. rules
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]